# Selecting non-empty elements

Tags: jquery

Let's say we have the following markup:

```
<p>
    foo
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
    bar
</p>
<p>
</p>
```

and we want to select paragraphs **which have some content visible to the user**. Is there a **way how to achieve this directly with a certain selector** or does one have to cycle through them?

Currently I'm stuck with this:

```
var paragraphs = $('p');
var nonEmptyParagraphs = [];
var curP;
for(var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++) {
    curP = $(paragraphs[i]);
    if(curP.text().length > 0) {
        nonEmptyParagraphs.push(curP);
    }
}
```

Thanks for advice!

Comment: `$('p:not(:empty)')`?

Comment: @billyonecan wouldn't `<p><span></span></p>` render not empty?

Comment: What you got inside result array i. e nonEmptyParagraphs.. try to print it.

Comment: @Dropout yes it would - you could filter: `var $nonEmptyParagraphs = $('p').filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).text() ).length; });`

Comment: I don't think there is a selector for it... youcan use `.filter()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny or `.each()`?

Comment: In CSS4, you would use `:blank` pseudo selector  https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-blank-pseudo

Comment: @A.Wolff good to know, thanks. But I need to do this in jQuery, because further logic follows after these elements are selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select non-empty do it like following.

```
$('p').filter(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim())
        return this;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't `<p><span></span></p>` render not empty though?

Comment: Won't work if any thing as e.g withe spaces is part of content

Comment: Answer was completely changed so previous comments are irrelevant. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the javascript trim() function to remove the blank space inside your `<p>` elements

```
    if(curP.text().trim().length > 0) {
       nonEmptyParagraphs.push(curP);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2606/